# How I can Binding c# class with BindingList inside?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have this c# class with BindingList

```
public class Jednotka
{
    // ~ctors

    public Jednotka()
    {
        CisloJednotky = "";
        PodilNaSVJCitatel = 0;
        PodilNaSVJJmenovatel = 1;
        TypJednotky = "";

        VlastniciJednotky = new BindingList<Vlastnik>();
    }

    public string CisloJednotky { get; set; }

    public int PodilNaSVJCitatel { get; set; }

    public int PodilNaSVJJmenovatel { get; set; }

    public string TypJednotky { get; set; }

    public BindingList<Vlastnik> VlastniciJednotky { get; set; }

}
```

and Class Vlastnik

```
 public class Vlastnik : Osoba
{

    public Vlastnik()
    {
        this.PodilNaJednotceCitatel = 0;
        this.PodilNaJednotceJmenovatel = 1;
        this.Bydliste = "";
        this.Jmeno = "";
    }


    public int PodilNaJednotceCitatel { get; set; } 

    public int PodilNaJednotceJmenovatel { get; set; } 
}
```

I need bind to DataGrid only "CisloJednotky" with the right "Jmeno".

In my program is a lot of "Jednotka" and each one may have one or more "Jmeno".

How I can show this two properties in DataGrid.

Can I use xaml Binding ?

I'll try this send to xaml

```
DataGridUcast.ItemsSource = SvJschuze.Jednotky;
```

and in xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridUcast" Grid.Row="1" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Jednotky/VlastniciJednotky}">
                <!--Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}"-->
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Číslo" Binding="{Binding CisloJednotky}" MinWidth="100"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Jméno" Binding="{Binding Path=Vlastnik.Jmeno}" MinWidth="330" Width="Auto"/>
                        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Účast" MinWidth="50"/>-->
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Účast" Binding="{Binding Pritomen, XPath=Pritomen}" MinWidth="50"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I'll tried to do more ways, but no success. I have only "CisloJednotky" inside DataGrid. But only one number although "CisloJednotky" have more "Vlastnik" with "Jmeno".

If don't underestand my code. I can send it again in english.

Thanks a lot for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.
Use helping class.

```
public class Data
    {
        // ~ctors
        public Data()
        {
            Jmeno = "";
            Cislo = "";
            Pritomen = false;
        }

        public BindingList<Data> NaplnData(SVJschuze svJschuze, BindingList<Data> dataList)
        {

            foreach (var jednotka in svJschuze.Jednotky)
            {
                foreach (var vlastnik in jednotka.VlastniciJednotky)
                {
                    Data data = new Data();
                    data.Cislo = jednotka.CisloJednotky;
                    data.Jmeno = vlastnik.Jmeno;
                    dataList.Add(data);
                }
            }

            return dataList;
        }

        // Fields and properties
        public string Jmeno { get; set; }

        public string Cislo { get; set; }

        public bool Pritomen { get; set; }
    }
```

and fill help class.

```
        Data data = new Data();
        DataList = new BindingList<Data>();
        data.NaplnData(SvJschuze, DataList);

        DataGridUcast.ItemsSource = DataList;
```

Work good for me.
Better be use DataGridComboBoxColumn in xaml for Vlastnik class.
Can choose the right name for Jednotka.
But I don't know how.